# Generate dates based on a date column -same day of week, same month

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame with 10,000+ dates. for example,

```
indexdt
01-02-2019
08-15-2019
```

I need to generate dates such that I get dates on the same day of week, same month and same year, i.e. 2019.  I also need to create the dates with the same condition for 2020.

Final Table for 2019:

```
indexdt     date
01-02-2019  01-09-2019
01-02-2019  01-16-2019
01-02-2019  01-23-2019
01-02-2019  01-30-2019
08-15-2019  08-01-2019
08-15-2019  08-08-2019
08-15-2019  08-22-2019
08-15-2019  08-29-2019
```

Final Table for 2020: (since 01-02-2019 falls on a Wednesday, all the wednesday dates from 2020 are selected.  Likewise since 08-15-2019 falls on a Thursday, all the Thursday dates from 2020 are selected

```
indexdt     date
01-02-2019  01-08-2020
01-02-2019  01-15-2020
01-02-2019  01-22-2020
01-02-2019  01-29-2020
08-15-2019  08-06-2020
08-15-2019  08-13-2020
08-15-2019  08-20-2020
08-15-2019  08-27-2020
```

I am looking for a data.table solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'indexdt' to `Date` class, loop over the elements, get a `seq`uence of dates with the end specified as the end of the month with `ceiling_date` (from `lubridate`) and specify `by` as "week" in a `list` and then `unnest` the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(indexdt = as.Date(indexdt, "%m-%d-%Y"),
     date = map(indexdt, ~ seq(.x, ceiling_date(.x, 'month'),
           by = 'week')[-1])) %>%
   unnest(c(date))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(df1)[, indexdt := as.Date(indexdt, "%m-%d-%Y")]
df1[, .(date = seq(indexdt, ceiling_date(indexdt, "month"),
         by = "week")[-1]), .(indexdt)]
```

For 2020, add one year

```
df1 %>%
   mutate(indexdt = as.Date(indexdt, "%m-%d-%Y"), 
    date = map(indexdt, ~ seq(.x + years(1), 
       ceiling_date(.x + years(1), 'month'), by = 'week')[-1])) %>% 
   unnest(c(date))
```

with `data.table`

```
df1[, .(date = seq(indexdt, ceiling_date(indexdt +years(1), "month"), 
      by = "week")[-1]), .(indexdt)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(indexdt = c("01-02-2019", "08-15-2019")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun.  Do you also have the solution in data.table?

Comment: @Pam yes, i do.  Can i use lubridate functions in that?

Comment: Thanks so much Akrun!   How would you do for the year 2020 in data.table?  I tried df1[, .(date = seq(indexdt, ceiling_date(indexed +year(1), "month"),
         by = "week")[-1]), .(indexed)] but this gives me an error-Error: Incompatible classes: <IDate> + <Period>

Comment: @Pam just change the `as.IDate` to `as.Date`.  updated

Comment: Thanks you so very much!